# Dynamically Remove Columns In Power Query By Header Dates

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a query table of data that has been merged in Power Query.  The result is monthly percentages for each person for two years that looks like this. I would like to dynamically remove months from the table when the month is over.  So, starting August 1st, July would be removed from the power query table when I refresh it.

Merged Query Table:

| **Name** | **Jul-21** | **Aug-21** | **Sept-21** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | .10 | .20 | .10 |
| Amy | .30 | .40 | .10 |

[image]

I've looked through StackOver, and there is one post that is similar to what I want to accomplish: [Table.RemoveColumns based on the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646662/table-removecolumns-based-on-the-date)

The code suggested in that post to remove column headers older than three years was:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    final = Table.SelectColumns(Source, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
            each try Date.From(_) >= Date.AddYears(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-3)
                 otherwise true))
in
    final
```

I went into the Advanced Editor in Power Query to try to adjust it to what I was trying to do, but the code does not work and no columns are removed. This is even before adjusting the code to not remove the current month.

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Merge1, Merge2}),
    final = Table.SelectColumns(Source, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
            each try Date.FromText(_) >= Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow())
                 otherwise true))
in
    final
```

I have tried both **each try Date.From(_)** and **each try Date.FromText(_)**, neither of which removed any columns. I have not altered the **Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow())** part of the equation in any of my tests.

I have tried to search for online resources to understand how this code works as well as used Microsoft's support site to learn about Table.SelectColumns and List.Select, but I have yet to find a good resource that can break down how to understand the above code, so it makes it difficult for me to understand what changes I need to make to get it work.

So far, I understand that the **List.Select** is determining the columns that will be included in the **Table.SelectColumns** function. **List.Select** is creating a list of all the column headers and then measuring their text (transformed by the **Date.FromText(_)** function into a date) against the current date using the **each try** and the **otherwise** is catching all the non-date headers and making sure they are included as well.

But I don't understand why the equation isn't removing any the past date columns or how to adjust the function (once it works) to not remove the current month. I would appreciate any assistance with both of these questions. I can share a link to the full spreadsheet if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 Table.SelectColumns(Source, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
   each try 
   Date.StartOfMonth(Date.FromText(Text.Start(_,3)&"/01/"&"20"&Text.End(_,2)))
   >= Date.StartOfMonth(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()))
   otherwise true))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have included a picture in the post.  It's the first situation. I've tried that code, but only the dates between January, 2022 and March, 2022 are being removed.  The Jul-21 to Dec-21 dates are remaining.  My columns do have 1.2 next to the header name instead of ABC123.  I can provide a shared link to the file in OneDrive if that would be helpful.

Comment: Solved.  Thank you so much!  My problem was that my date format was storing Jan-21 as Jan 21, 2022.